# How to create an executable with a pycharm python file though pyinstaller?

Tags: python, exe

I have been trying to install pyinstaller in order to create an executable of a python project I have been working on, but my pip command simply doesn't work. This is the error I would get "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". I have already checked the interpreter of my pycharm project, and it shows that it has pip already installed. I tried to look this up online, and I found out that a problem could be that the environment variable Path just needs to have the directory of my python version, but even after doing this, it still would not work. For additional information, I already tried to find the directory by using the command "where python" in the command prompt, but that path didn't work, and I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for most of users, there would be a problem as you mention above. In such situation, you just need to install pip again with command like

```
python -m pip3 install -U pip
```

and remember next time, if pip reminds you to upgrade it, do not just use

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: If you format your answer, it becomes easier to read. See [Markdon help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)